# How to get the pointer of std::ostream.write for serializing

Tags: c++

I try here to serialize a object without using BOOST library and for this, i use an std::ostream object and the method write like this :

```
obj object;
  std::ostream stream;
  stream.write((char *)&object,sizeof(obj));
```

What i want to do is put this stream into an array of byte and send the pointer of this array to an other function of deserialization.

But i don't know how to get this pointer and to cast this object into and array and to get the pointer !

if anyone can answer my question it's would be great !

Comment: What type is `obj`? You cannot serialize complex types like that.

Comment: And `&object` already points to the _array of bytes_. It's not clear to me what you want to accomplish.

Comment: `obj` is a simple class with two attributes : int att1 and char att2

Comment: what i'm trying to do here , is to serialize an object into a array of byte , but i don't know how to do this , and the problem is i cannot use boost

Comment: As long as your classes contain only POD types this might work as intended, but I guess you want to serialize arbitrary classes.

Comment: yes , this have to work with any classes , but for the moment i try to do it with a simple one

Comment: A pointer is meaningless to a function in a different process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Serialization of arbitrary class types is a complicated topic. It is **not** sufficient to just take the base address of the object instance and copy `sizeof(whatever)` bytes. This might work for very simple classes with members of POD type but think of a simple `std::string` type member which has already heap allocated memory outside of the object instance's memory block. You'd have to follow all pointers to their respective memory location and copy the content there as well and so on.

Only your class itself knows how to properly serialize/deserialize itself and it's also the only one who has access to private members. **One possible approach** would be to add serialization/deserialization functions to your class. You could (should) also put this into a base class/interface then:

```
class ISerializable
{
public:
  virtual void Serialize(std::ostream& stream) const = 0;
  virtual void Deserialize(std::istream& stream) = 0;
}
```

Derive serializable classes from this and implement the virtual functions. Make sure the serializer writes the data of all members to the stream or calls `Serialize()` functions of class type members. If you have `std::string` members or other types that you can't modify use their public interface to extract all data needed in order to restore them later. This would be the char buffer data and/or length in case of the `std::string`. For POD types like `int` it is sufficient to copy the memory data in some way similar to what you posted.

Please note that all your serializable classes need a default constructor when using the pattern mentioned above since you have to create an instance before you can actually deserialize its content from an `istream`.

Comment: yes i just saw that by doing a sizeof(stream) before and after doing the stream.write() , i really don't know how to do that